# ListView does not refresh from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I made an App to refresh the state of WiFi every 5 seconds. Here's the main Activity

```
public class WiFiList extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private String screen;
private ListView nets;
private WifiManager wifi;
private NetAdapter nAdap;
SharedPreferences getPrefs;
Updater skaner;
List<ScanResult> scan;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String screen = getPrefs.getString("start", "list");
    wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(screen.equals("list")){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        nets = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNets);
        wifi.startScan();
        scan = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
        nAdap = new NetAdapter(getApplicationContext(), scan);
        nets.setAdapter(nAdap);
        nAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    skaner = new Updater();
    skaner.execute();
}

public void refresh(){
    nAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class Updater extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // doSomething();
        while(wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
            int waiter = getPrefs.getInt("intervals", 5) * 1000;
            wifi.startScan();
            scan = wifi.getScanResults();
            publishProgress();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(waiter);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(isCancelled()){
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        refresh();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    skaner.cancel(true);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

However the ListView doesn't refresh. When I run the debugger I see that `refresh()` is called and that the list has different values every time. What stops it from refreshing? When I have it scan the networks in `onCreate()`, they appear on the list, so I assume that adapter is correct, but here's the code anyway:

```
public class NetAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
List<ScanResult> res;

public NetAdapter(Context context, List<ScanResult> l){
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    res = l;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return res.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return res.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.netitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvFreq = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFreq);
        holder.tvRssi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRssi);
        holder.ivState = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivSignal);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }   
    holder.tvName.setText(res.get(position).SSID +" (" + res.get(position).BSSID + ")");
    holder.tvFreq.setText(Integer.toString(res.get(position).frequency)+"MHz");
    holder.tvRssi.setText(Integer.toString(res.get(position).level)+"dBm");
    holder.ivState.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvFreq;
    TextView tvRssi;
    ImageView ivState;
}
```

Comment: try to use `invalidateViews()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use below method of AsyncTask for updating List view .

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that run only after doInBackground is finished? In my app it runs continuously.

Comment: DynamicMind is right, you need a `onPostExecute` Method and there you should call i.e. `onCompleteTask` Method of your own interface, it's not mandatory but it helps to modularize and you'll have a better overview. The activity from you call your Custom `AsyncTask` should implement this `onCompleteTask` from whom you should have available Data.  If it wouldn't be like this, you could always develop your own Event and its associated Listener to wait until it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `startScan()` returns immediately and the availability of results is made known asynchronously when the results are available. so when you read the scan results straight after the call to `startscan()` the results are most likely not there hence you are sending blank information to the adapter.

So this covers why your view is not refreshing. So how do you make sure that you only read results when they are available. See recommendation below.

it will be better to use the BroadcastReceiver to receive the scan results. Register for `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`

so you run the scan in your async but don't do any refreshes from there just use it keep your loop running. you can use just a thread for that as well if you wanted to.

To update simply make a call back from your receiver back to your activity where you read the scan results.

I also noticed that your are calling `startscan()` in `onCreate` and then straight after you create an Async task to do the same again. what is the point of doing that.

Comment: As I said. I checked in debugger and the list is full of correct data each time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly.

Assumptions:
1.You are updating the values in the adapter

Solution:

To refresh the list view all you need to do is:

```
your_list_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: That's what i do in the line `nAdap.notifyDataSetChanged()`